# remove last slash and extensions and also handle error pages by htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website where there are many directories like `test` so when I open my website with `domain.com/test` it gives me `domain.com/test/` **I want this last slash to be removed**.

I also want to remove the extention so that when I open a page like `page.php`
it gives me `domain.com/page`

In addition,  I want to send all the error pages to `domain.com/error404`
and I do have added code for non `http` to `https`

This is my current attempt:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]

ErrorDocument 403 /www.domain.com/error404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /https://www.domain.com/error404.php
```

https is working correctly but I also want to remove the last slash and extensions and handle error pages which currently do not work.

Comment: Removing trailing slash from a URL that points to a directory is a security issue.

Comment: @anubhava please suggest me something for these things i dont want the extensions and don want to show the index.php file as well and also error page to error404.php.

Comment: ok check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php

RewriteEngine On

# redirect to https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Sir, i dont want to show any index in url. right now i am its like domain.com/index/

and also the images do not load becasue there is no index folder in the site.
can wo hide the index from url make it like domain.com or domain.com/folder-name

Comment: i think there is problem with post data while submiting the form .. PLease update this sir, the form post data has some issues ..

Comment: can you help me here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888268/php-codeigniter-htaccess-remove-controller-name-and-index-php-and-rewrite-url

Answer (score 0):

You can turn of directory slashes using:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

or you can remove that trailling slash with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

and redirecting the errors can be:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/error404
```