# PHP Codeigniter Htaccess. Remove controller name and index.php and rewrite url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Hello all i have been working on a new project in Codeigniter and everything is working great except one thing that is url

What i want is to remove the controller name **main** and the word **index.php** from my URL 
like my url is right now like this

> Current URL: www.domain.com/index.php/main/contact

**where main = controller name and contact is function name**

> Needed url: www.domain.com/contact

i know that i can remove index.php and controller name by htaccess and i have also achieved it some what bt ***the problem is all of my links in the website is already lined as domain.com/index.php/main/contact***  so i want something which can automatically redirect the url to the required url without index.php and controller name.

> Note: controller name is always "main"

My htaccess file is like this in root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help in this manner is highly appreciated.
also i do not want to have any problem with my form submitions as they have the action urls etc.

Comment: Please follow each step https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: Be sure your `.htaccess` file should be in root dir. not in system folder also remove `.htaccess` file from `application` folder @Lisa

Comment: Give this a shot if others fail. This has always worked for me. Fool proof every time. Regardless of the framework.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35014499/3532758

Comment: i can remove the index.php from url but i want ot to be auto redirected too.

Comment: CI has it's own rewrite router that may not always play nice with .htaccess rewrites.

Comment: @anubhava hi i am very happy to receive your comment, i know the route.php in CI, but my main problem is that i have already added all links as domain.com/index.php/main/contact and i want the htaccess to redirect automatically to domain.com/contact

Comment: With the current rules as shown, if you enter `domain.com/contact ` in browser, does it load correct content?

Comment: @anubhava yes it does load it correctly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule **just below `RewriteEngine On` line as your topmost rule**:

```
# remove /index.php/main/ from URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php/main/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/main(/.*)?$ https://%1$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine , this is awesome i knew you will help me yo are the best . 
just one last question i have many urls to rewrite like this so should i just all the urls like $route['contact'] = 'main/contact'; in route.php or it can be automatic also ??

Comment: It can be automatic in a standard htacceas setup but you are using CI framework that I don't know well enough to say the same with full surely

Comment: i can try if you let me know how to do that on standard, i will update the standard htaccess and i think will work with CI too ! Regards

Comment: got the answer 

$route['(:any)'] = "main/$1"; for routes.php

Comment: i am getting err_http2_ping_failed 200, for images and the images does not load when i use the above code in my website as htaccess. any advice sir ??

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471804/how-to-replace-and-from-url-with-by-htaccess-in-php-ci can you check this please ?

Comment: Sorry I am traveling for few days. Will check this once I am back

Comment: when ever you are back please check if you can help. thankx

Answer (score 2):

**1)** To remove `index.php` from the URL you can follow this
[CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

**2)** To rewrite your url from `www.domain.com/index.php/main/contact` to `www.domain.com/contact` you have to do the routing in `application->config->routes.php`. Like this

```
$route['contact'] = 'main/contact';
```

Comment: its awesome , works but what i want is something from htaccess which redirects auto from main url to preferred url.

Comment: how can i do it for all the links in the website automatically ???

Comment: $route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";

Comment: its working great but not loading this perticular page 

domain.com/index.php/admin