# how to replace ?= and & from url with / by htaccess in PHP CI

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello all i am new with htaccess and i dont know how to make my url SEO friendly, please do guide me little here

```
here is my url domain.com/article?seo=What-Software&id=7

required url domain.com/article/What-Software/7
can also accept as domain.com/article/What-Software/id/7
```

here is my current htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
# remove /index.php/main/ from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php/main/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/main(/.*)?$ https://%1$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# remove main
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /main [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)main$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

please guide me how to do that as i need to make the url simpler for SEO
also i dont want to messup with any form post

Comment: If you enter `domain.com/article/What-Software/7` in browser now, does it load correct page content or not?

Comment: no it says 404 error

Comment: You will have to add a CI routing rule to handle `domain.com/article/What-Software/7` kind of URLs.